# Como deixar um layout preparado para todas as resoluções

Tags: css3

Sei que parece confuso, existe algum meio para que um layout fique "preparado" para ficar visível de forma responsiva quando o cliente redimensionar o navegador e para qualquer dispositivo?

Comment: A forma mais simples é usar algum framework responsivo.
Os mais populares talvez sejam: Bootstrap, Foundation 3, Skeleton, existem vários.

Comment: de uma olhada nesse: [artigo](http://tableless.com.br/design-responsivo-na-pratica-2-layout-ao-html/) é muito bem explicado, não tem como não entender...

Comment: Essa pergunta foi muito boa, me lembrem de deixar uma recompensa aqui assim que puder.

Comment: Você pode dizer o que será de resolução x ate resolução y, para cada variação de resolução https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967842/automatically-change-css-when-resolution-is-changed

Comment: A dica do @Jader foi interessante, já tinha visto o site mas nunca essa seção, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se quiser fazer isso do princípio até ao fim, recomendo a combinação de `media queries` combinado com dimensões relativas dos elementos da página (em vez de pixeis usar % ou .em para fontes).

**Media Queries:**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_queries (Para conhecimento geral e abertura)
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ (Especificação mais completa)
http://designshack.net/articles/css/20-amazing-examples-of-using-media-queries-for-responsive-web-design/ (Alguns exemplos)

Outra alternativa seria utilizar um framework, que trataria da "responsividade" da tua página:

http://designinstruct.com/roundups/html5-frameworks/ (Top 10 dos frameworks mais utilizados, escolha e use)

Acredito que com estas diretrizes já há uma ideia do que procurar.

Comment: Olá @Cold, muito obrigado pelas excelentes dicas, com certeza estão me ajudando muito.

Answer (score 13):

Algumas considerações:

### Resolução

A primeira, e mais óbvia, diferença de renderização entre dispositivos que você precisa prestar atenção é a resolução, geralmente medida em **pixels** - o número de pontos em cada tela. Como regra simples, quanto mais *pixels* maior é o espaço para exibição de elementos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém outro fator deve ser levado em consideração:

### Densidade

A densidade de um dispositivo equivale à quantidade de *pixels* que podem ser representados em uma dada área. A medida mais comum é o **DPI** (do inglês *dots per inch*, pontos por polegada). Minha experiência é que este é o ponto de maior conflito quando desenhando um solução web que sirva tanto para visualizações em desktop quanto em dispositivos mobile: Muitos celulares hoje em dia possuem resoluções maiores do que monitores padrão 1080p.

O resultado é visualmente similar à distorção por resolução, com o fator adicional que sua interface no dispositivo móvel estará extremamente reduzida.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para auxiliar o desenvolvimento de sites responsivos, o padrão CSS3 introduziu as chamadas **media queries**, onde comportamentos diferentes podem ser associados a resoluções diferentes:

```
@media(max-width:767px){}
@media(min-width:768px){}
@media(min-width:992px){}
@media(min-width:1200px){}
```

Para complicar sua vida, dispositivos como o iPad não reportam mudanças no tamanho do *viewport* quando rotacionados (mudando de modo *portrait* para *landscape*, por exemplo.)

### Viewport scaling

Uma das saídas é desligar o fator de zoom em dispositivos mobile causado pela densidade maior, usando a seguinte tag meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Este é um exemplo de página visualizada sem o meta viewport (esquerda) e com o viewport ajustado (direita):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado @OnoSendai, estou lendo tudo o que está sendo postado, valeu pela ajuda.

Comment: @adventistapr É sempre um prazer ajudar; sinta-se à vontade para trazer qualquer dúvida que eventualmente possua.

Comment: +1 excelente resposta!

Answer (score 12):

Você precisa usar as [media queries](http://tableless.com.br/introducao-sobre-media-queries) com estilos `css` para formatar o seu código conforme a resolução usada. Exemplo de media queries:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) { html, body {background-color: red} }
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) { html, body {background-color: green} }
@media screen and (min-width: 640px) { html, body {background-color: yellow} }
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) { html, body {background-color: blue} }
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) { html, body {background-color: gray} }
```

Se reparar, para cada resolução de tela o atributo `background-color` troca de cor.

Poderá escrever suas **media queries** direto dentro das folhas de estilos **.css** ou entre as tags `<style></style>` dentro de um arquivo `html` ou `php` ou extensões dos mesmos.

Visto que as **media queries** não são bem recebidas pelo **IE8** e anteriores, uma das soluções para tentar aproximar-se do resultado desejado nesses navegadores é incluir o seguinte código no seu conteúdo para web:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Isso permitirá que as **media queries** sejam reconhecidas pelos browsers citados.

Comment: Eu tentei dar uma explicada ali, mas um exemplo vale mais do que mil explicações. :P +1

Comment: Tem que ficar atento que o @media dá dor de cabeça com o IE8.

Comment: Complementando quando usar @media eu recomendo escrever na ordem crescente, ex: min-width: 320px, 480.. (Porque você está falando: largura mínima(min-width) p/ aplicar esse estilo, como o menor está por último ele sempre vai pegar ele, porque a regra é o "mínimo" valor e não "a partir de".

Comment: Olá @Marcos Vinicius Nasc. Pereira, KaduAmaral e Felipe Stoker, sou grato a atenção de cada um de vocês, estou lendo e acompanhando cada dica, que para mim estão sendo preciosas.

Answer (score 2):

Existe sim, e é chamado de **Design Responsivo**. Onde é definido todos os layouts para diversas resoluções.

E o que abriu as portas para esse design foi as ***media querys***.

Recomendo estudar o assunto a fundo se você deseja ser um web designer.

Comment: Olá @KaduAmaral, sobre as media querys já tinha usado em alguns pequenos projetos mas agora estou envolvido em site maior, valeu pela dica.