# Uma imagem com display:none é carregado? Consome dados?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Estou desenvolvendo um *layout* responsivo e gostaria de diminuir o tamanho das imagens conforme a resolução.

Eu utilizei o `display: none` porém vi no `inspetor de elementos` que ela está sendo carregada. Está sendo consumido os dados das duas imagens? Qual alternativa para este problema?

Comment: Trabalhando com media query você carrega somente o que precisa para a resolução escolhida

Comment: Certo cara, mais qual método você utiliza para isto? com `display: none`.. ela é carregada em todas as medias.

Comment: em vez de carregar via html coloca elas no css e usa media query

Comment: Entendi, com o background.. Obrigado

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neste [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158540/does-displaynone-prevent-an-image-from-loading) um usuário fez um teste no Chrome, Internet Explorer, Firefox e Opera e eles tratam isso de formas diferentes.

Se as imagens estiverem em uma tag `img` elas serão baixadas por todos. Mas se estiverem como `background-image` de um elemento apenas o Firefox e o Opera não baixam. O IE e Chrome só não vão baixar caso a imagem não se encaixe na regra definida no `media-query`.

Answer (score 5):

Como já pode comprovar é carregada e tudo o que é carregado consome dados, não tem milagre.

Certamente existem técnicas para evitar a carga das duas. A carga pode ser seletiva no que realmente será usado. Isto pode ser feito [com JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21726/101) ou com CSS ([media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)). Tem [pergunta sobre isto aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33732/101).

Answer (score 3):

Primeira coisa que deve entender é :

- [Quando devo usar a tag  ou a propriedade do CSS background?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/190527/quando-devo-usar-a-tag-img-ou-a-propriedade-do-css-background)

Caso a sua imagem não tenha valor semântico use a propriedade `background-image`  + `display:none` em uma `div`, isso evitará que sua imagem seja carregada.

## Edição

Analisando a situação percebi que a resposta que adicionei acima não é verdadeira, ou seja, pelo ao menos no caso do `Google Crome` está imagem é baixada.

*Veja você mesmo:*

```css
div#image { 
   background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/736x/6b/b2/49/6bb249802cf0c124fde0ccbcea699340--funny-stuff-quotes.jpg");
   width:500px;
   height:500px;
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id='image'>
</div>
```

Você pode ver isto na aba `NetWork`, coloquei também uma imagem para ilustrar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Porque é necessário que a imagem carregue?

Devido a possibilidade de um `Script` verificar dinamicamente um elemento do `DOM`, o navegador não otimiza elementos ou seus conteúdos.

<sub>Fonte: [Does “display:none” prevent an image from loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158540/does-displaynone-prevent-an-image-from-loading)</sub>